# How do I a read a useragent string?

Tags: php, browser, user-agent

I'm tracking the user agent via PHP for an app I'm building for some troubleshooting.

How do I read these strings? (I'm looking for OS, browser, and version) Are they in a standard format? Here are a few examples:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; HTC-A9192/1.0 Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 3.0.04506; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; SLCC1)
```

Comment: Do you mean how do you obtain the useragent string, or do you mean how do you parse / pick apart the useragent string?

Comment: AFAIK there is no standardized User-Agent string. Trying to extract a format from them is useless as any user can modify their User-Agent.

Comment: I'm looking for OS, browser, and version.

Comment: I don't have time for that at the moment, but the PHP framework called CodeIgniter has some good browser sniffing functions, maybe you can look into it's source for some clues.

Comment: See [get_browser()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)  This can return that info for you.  It requires that you download a browsecap.ini file from a 3rd party and make it available from php.ini however.  If you can do that, it will save you a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is why browser sniffing (reading the browser string), is usually considered bad practice, although it is sometimes necessary. There is not a real standard for this. In the examples above, the browser name is the beginning of the line untill the slash, which is followed by the version, and a space. After that follows some platform information between brackets. But, as you can see in the 3rd line, the first word doesn't need to be the platform, it can also specify a compatibility mode. And these are only some of the browser strings.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If what you're saying is true, then in each of these examples, more than one browser is being reported.

Comment: no. Some browsers can run in compatibility mode, or in case of, for example safari, run as if it is a different browser.

Comment: That is definitely not happening. The client base using this app are not technical at all. I'm not saying it doesn't happen, but the odds are small that the users have configured their browsers to run in compatibility mode (unless this mode is on by default).